# Redirect to the filtered list in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Suppose, I have a modelA and modelB, that has ForeignKey relationship with modelA

On the any modelA object page in Django Admin, I would like to have a link to the filtered list of modelB instances that have the relationship with that modelA instance.

For example:

From `/admin/my_app/modelA/1/change/`, I would like to access `/admin/my_app/modelB/?modelA__id__exact=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the reverse URL with the URL encoded parameters. Here's a small function to do just that:

```py
from django.utils.http import urlencode

def reverse_with_parameters(
    view_name: str,
    parameters: dict[str, Any | None],
    args: tuple | None = None,
) -> str:
    base_url = reverse(view_name) if args is None else reverse(view_name, args=args)
    return f"{base_url}?{urlencode(parameters)}"
```

You can call it like this:

```py
change_url = reverse('admin:myapp_modelb_change', {'q': 1})
```

Answer (score -2):

To create the complete URL to the admin change view including filter:

1. reverse the URL

According to the list in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls
you can dynamically create the URL from the model and app label.

This is the pattern: `{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_changelist`

In your case:

```
# in models.py
class MyModel(Model):
    # you're model fields

# in admin.py in some Admin class
model_cls = MyModel
change_url = reverse(f'admin:{model_cls._meta.app_label}_{model_cls._meta.model_name}_changelist')
```

2. add the filter parameter

As in all regular `reverse()` calls, add the parameter to the `kwargs` keyword argument list.

On the changelist, the search parameter is `q`.

Define the searchfields in your admin.py:

```
   search_fields = ['modelA__id__exact']
```

Then get the url like this:

```
change_url = reverse('admin:myapp_modelb_change', kwargs={'q': 1})
```

Comment: This will raise a `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch`: The admin changelist url pattern is defined to be `'{admin_url}/{app_label}/{model_name}/\\Z'`.

Comment: to everyone who downgraded and @Joren - I don't care about the votes but you imply to others that my answer is not correct, while I'm not really writing anything different from the docs that are additionally linked - and where you should actually check. So, I'm really wondering - have you actually tried to understand what is written here and in the docs? It seems you do not see the difference between using the hard coded URL and the `reverse` call.

Comment: No I actually checked: In my django project `reverse('admin:review_review_changelist')` returns `'/admin/review/review/'`, but `reverse('admin:review_review_changelist', kwargs={'status__exact': 'R'})`  raises a `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch`. Your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: The referenced documentation does not mention any allowed parameters for the `changelist` view either...

Comment: Just don't add the "__exact" suffix, it's not needed.

Comment: My point is that this answer is wrong and will crash your webserver. I only used the the `__exact` suffix because that's what you literally wrote in your answer, and completely irrelevant here...

Comment: Please compare your code example from Aug 5 with my code, they are clearly different. You use `__exact` in the kwargs to the admin which of course does not work. That's why my code sets `search_fields` and then uses `q` as kwarg. Only your webserver crashed.

Comment: The crash also occurs without `__exact`. The issue is that all the parameters of an url pattern must be explicitly defined within the `urls.py`. Additionally, `reverse` with `**kwargs` doesn't magically add the kwargs as query string, which your answer seems to suggest. But don't take my word for it; try it yourself: your answer is plain wrong.